# Get File As base64 from plupload file uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am using the Plupload Uploader , what am trying to implement is after the file is uploaded i wont to convert the file to base64 and send it in a soap envelop , i managed to create an envelop and use my web-service , now my question is how can i get the file as base64 in the uploader.bind 'FileUploaded' :

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file) {

}
```

Best Regards,

Comment: I Cant even find a way to get the file content it self

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, if using an HTML5 supported browser

```
UploadFile: function (up, file) {
  var reader = new window.FileReader();

  reader.readAsDataURL(file.getNative());

  reader.onload = function () {
    base64data = reader.result;
    base64data = base64data.substring(base64data.indexOf(",") + 1);
  }
}
```